# Searching within a percentile in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Elastic supports finding values for a given percentile. I have a somewhat different case and I'm wondering if elastic can help. Given a set of documents with two properties, id and value, I wish to find a list of ids within a given percentile range of a given value. For example, if documents with ids 1, 2 and 3 have values in 50th percentile, and I'm looking for documents within 45-55 percentiles, I would get 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Partially. Is it possible in a single step?

Comment: When you already know those IDs lie in that percentile, why would you need a percentile-ish query? Go with a range query with concrete values... Percentile aggs are used when you don't know what the concrete value bounds are.

Comment: I don't know upfront which ids go where.